# When should i send a variable through a class initialization or a getter method?

Tags: java

I have a screen set up and I want to send the width and height to another class. Should I send the width and height variables to the second class in the initialization of the second class: `ClassB b = new ClassB(width, height);` or would it be better to just create a `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` method in `classA` and then create an instance of `ClassA` in `classB` to call the getter methods?

EDIT: I feel like creating an instance of `classA` in `classB` would be bad programming because it is unnessary besides the fact that I need the `width` and `height`.

Comment: Your gut instinct is correct

Answer (score 1):

Getters **get** values, setters **set** values. You probably mean setters.

It depends on what you want to do:

**1. Can the `width` and `height` be changed after creating the instance?**

*Yes:* Create a setter method and see No. 2.

*No:* use the constructor.

**2. Are `width` and `height` core business of your class?**

*Yes:* Use a constructor to set them initially .

*No:* There's no need to use a constructor.

Either way you probably want getters to ensure encapsulation of your `width` and `height` variables (they should be declared `private`).

Comment: To be honest your question is worded pretty difficult. If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and add some clarification to your exact situation. I'm not 100% sure if I got the idea behind the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it sounds like class A has data besides height and width that is irrelevant to class B, in which case you shouldn't really give class B the instance of class A. You'll probably want getters in class A regardless, since you probably don't want the values being updated at whim by any other object in the code, which means width and height should be private variables in class A.

If width and height are required for class B, I would make them part of B's constructor. Otherwise, I would write 2 (or 4) constructors, one with no parameters, and 1 that takes both width and height (if you really want to be thorough, you can write 2 more constructors - that take just a height and just a width respectively). This will give users the option of passing the values along when an object of type B is instantiated. In that instance, you'll also need setters for height and width in class B so a user can set them after instantiating an object of type B.

Answer (score 0):

In your context, it would be a good practice to implement the getter and setter methods you have mentioned.
No need to create an instance of ClassA inside ClassB. Personally, I would do it like this:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA(width, height);
ClassB b = new ClassB(a.getWidth(), a.getHeight());
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions don't change, I would define them public final.

```
public class ClassA{
   public final width;
   public final height;
   ClassA(width, height){
      this.height=height; 
      this.width=width;
   }
}
```

To call them:

```
public class ClassB{
   private final width;
   private final height;
   ClassB(ClassA in){
      this.height=in.height; 
      this.width=in.width;
   }
}
```

Why? **in.getWidth();** vs **in.width;:** you save five symbols.

That's a productivity enhancement of 55% right there.